# How to save in localstorage transfered rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

What I want is

```js
$(function() {
  function moveRow(row, targetTable, newLinkText){
    $(row)
    .appendTo(targetTable)
    .find("A")
    .text(newLinkText);
  }

  $("#FIRST A").live("click", function(){
    moveRow($(this).parents("tr"), $("#SECOND"), "Add");
  });

  $("#SECOND A").live("click", function(){
    moveRow($(this).parents("tr"), $("#FIRST"), "Delete");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE ID="FIRST"></TABLE>

<hr />

<TABLE ID="SECOND"> 
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>First Value</TD>
    <TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>Second Value</TD>
    <TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>...</TD>
    <TD>...</TD>
    <TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UxRVa/1/

Things that are shown in example. If you import row from first table I would like to have it saved after refreshing page. I tried to do it for hours with tons of different ways and each of them failed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to store and read from `localStorage`:

```
$('#FIRST A,#SECOND A').live('click', function() {
   localStorage.setItem('FIRST',$('#FIRST').html());
   localStorage.setItem('SECOND',$('#SECOND').html());
});

var first = localStorage.getItem('FIRST');
var second = localStorage.getItem('SECOND');
!first || $('#FIRST').html(first);
!second || $('#SECOND').html(second);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxRVa/47/)

**UPDATE**

A much better approach than that above would be to create a `saveTables` function which should be called every time **after** any changes have been made:

```js
$(function() {
   function moveRow(row, targetTable, newLinkText){
       $(row)
           .appendTo(targetTable)
           .find("A")
               .text(newLinkText);
     saveTables();
   }
   function saveTables() {
     localStorage.setItem('FIRST',$('#FIRST').html());
     localStorage.setItem('SECOND',$('#SECOND').html());     
   }
   
   $("#FIRST A").live("click", function(){
       moveRow($(this).parents("tr"), $("#SECOND"), "Add");
   });

   $("#SECOND A").live("click", function(){
       moveRow($(this).parents("tr"), $("#FIRST"), "Delete");
   });
  
   var first = localStorage.getItem('FIRST');
   var second = localStorage.getItem('SECOND');
   !first || $('#FIRST').html(first);
   !second || $('#SECOND').html(second);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE ID="FIRST">
</TABLE>
    
<hr />

<TABLE ID="SECOND"> 
<TR>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>First Value</TD>
<TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>Second Value</TD>
<TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>...</TD>
<TD>...</TD>
<TD><A HREF="#">Add</A></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, I just have a weird problem when I try it on my server. My table list quite bigger and that localstorage saves things by doesn't saves and removes last add things. So If I add only 1 thing to another table, it doesn't saves anything at all. If I add 2 things, it saves only 1 thing. Not sure why x_ x

Comment: Perhaps the tables are being saved to `localStorage` before the changes occur. Would you try the update above?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that. The items from table one are generated from database, not sure if it could cause it. @PeterKA

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concern. The update I have suggested seems like a trivial change to what you've already tried.

Comment: Of course it does saves at local storage, just for unknown reasons do not saves last added things. If I add 5 things to 2nd table only first 4 are saved after browser refresh. I mentioned database, cause all things in 1st table are generated from database.. and thought that it would have something to do with that problem. No idea T_ T

Comment: @Harugawa did you make the suggested change? It should solve the issue you've described. Click `Show code snippet` in my answer above to see where to make the changes. Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Works like a charm, sorry I haven't noticed that update before D:. Thank you